# How to convert complex SQL query to spark-dataframe using python or Scala

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have done one transformation using sqlcontext in spark but same query I want to write using Spark Data frame only . This query include join operation plus case statement of SQL.
The sql query written as below:

```
refereshLandingData=spark.sql( "select a.Sale_ID, a.Product_ID,"
                           "CASE "
                           "WHEN (a.Quantity_Sold IS NULL) THEN b.Quantity_Sold "
                           "ELSE a.Quantity_Sold "
                           "END AS Quantity_Sold, "
                           "CASE "
                           "WHEN (a.Vendor_ID IS NULL) THEN b.Vendor_ID "
                           "ELSE a.Vendor_ID "
                           "END AS Vendor_ID, "
                           "a.Sale_Date, a.Sale_Amount, a.Sale_Currency "
                           "from landingData a left outer join preHoldData b on a.Sale_ID = b.Sale_ID" )
```

now I want equvalent code in spark dataframe in both scala and python. I have tried some code but its
not working .my tried code is as follow:

```
joinDf=landingData.join(preHoldData,landingData['Sale_ID']==preHoldData['Sale_ID'],'left_outer')

joinDf.withColumn\
('QuantitySold',pf.when(pf.col(landingData('Quantity_Sold')).isNull(),pf.col(preHoldData('Quantity_Sold')))
.otherwise(pf.when(pf.col(preHoldData('Quantity_Sold')).isNull())),
 pf.col(landingData('Quantity_Sold'))).show()
```

In the above code joining done perfectly but case condition not working.
I am getting--> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
I am using spark 2.3.2 version and python 3.7 and similarly scala 2.11 in case of spark-scala
Please anyone suggest me any equivalent code or guidence !

Comment: check your Python code because you are trying to call a function from a dataframe instance

Answer (score 3):

Here's a scala solution :
Assuming `landingData` and `preHoldData` are your dataframes

```
 val landingDataDf = landingData.withColumnRenamed("Quantity_Sold","Quantity_Sold_ld")
 val preHoldDataDf = preHoldData.withColumnRenamed("Quantity_Sold","Quantity_Sold_phd")

 val joinDf = landingDataDf.join(preHoldDataDf, Seq("Sale_ID"))


 joinDf
 .withColumn("Quantity_Sold",
    when(col("Quantity_Sold_ld").isNull , col("Quantity_Sold_phd")).otherwise(col("Quantity_Sold_ld"))
 ). drop("Quantity_Sold_ld","Quantity_Sold_phd")
```

You can do the same way for Vendor_id

The problem with your code is, you cannot reference the other/old dataframe names in `withColumn` operation. It has to be from the dataframe that you are operating.

Comment: this code working fine but the issue is both the dataframe has same column names and we have to renamed each of that column otherwise not able to select required column.we want just selected column with this case not all.

Comment: @AliBinmazi you can easily drop columns. Edited the answer to drop the unwanted columns.

Comment: now this code work fine when we add drop() . thanks @Sanket9394

Comment: @AliBinmazi cool. Do consider accepting it as the answer if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work on scala & for python you might tune little bit.

```
val preHoldData = spark.table("preHoldData").alias("a")
val landingData = spark.table("landingData").alias("b")

landingData.join(preHoldData,Seq("Sale_ID"),"leftouter")
.withColumn("Quantity_Sold",when(col("a.Quantity_Sold").isNull, col("b.Quantity_Sold")).otherwise(col("a.Quantity_Sold")))
.withColumn("Vendor_ID",when(col("a.Vendor_ID").isNull, col("b.Vendor_ID")).otherwise(col("a.Vendor_ID")))
.select(col("a.Sale_ID"),col("a.Product_ID"),col("Quantity_Sold"),col("Vendor_ID"),col("a.Sale_Date"),col("a.Sale_Amount"),col("a.Sale_Currency"))
```

Comment: Its working fine till withcolumn function but when we applying .select function giving ambiguity issue with col("Quantity_Sold").I have tried with renaming it but still not working.

Comment: Ok, check @Sanket9394 his solution.. he has explained clearly... :)